# Cannot find symbol when already declared

Tags: java

Please someone help me on this error :

```
import java.util.*;
class Cinema
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cat;
        System.out.println("Choose your category : \n 1)Premium - Rs.150 \n 2)Gold - Rs.200 \n 3)Business Class - Rs.400");
        cat = sc.nextInt();
        switch(cat)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Premium");
                int t = 150;   /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Gold");
                int t = 200;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Business Class");
                int t = 400;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Option");
            break;
        }
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, amt;
        System.out.println("Choose number of tickets");
        n = num.nextInt();
        amt = t * n;      /* ERROR : cannot find symbol - variable t */
        System.out.println("You are buying " +n+ " tickets of " +cat+ " for Rs." +amt);
    }
}
```

I have already declared the variable t in a case block but it cant find it.
I looked through many answers to similar questions but i cant seem to solve it

Comment: It would be better if you showed the error message in the question and not just in the code comments. As it is, it makes it harder to see what the problem is.

Comment: Declare t outside the scope of switch block (`int t;`) and assign value to it within each case block (`t = 150;`) then you won't get this error. This is a simple scope issue. A variable defined in a block is only visible inside it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare your variable before switch block for it to be accessible outside of the switch block ... please see the below

```
import java.util.*;
public class Cinema {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int cat;
    System.out.println("Choose your category : \n 1)Premium - Rs.150 \n 2)Gold - Rs.200 \n 3)Business Class - Rs.400");
    cat = sc.nextInt();

    int t = 0;
    switch(cat)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            System.out.println("You have selected Premium");
             t = 150;   /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            System.out.println("You have selected Gold");
            t = 200;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            System.out.println("You have selected Business Class");
            t = 400;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
            break;
        }
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Option");
            break;
    }
    Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n, amt;
    System.out.println("Choose number of tickets");
    n = num.nextInt();
    amt = t * n;      /* ERROR : cannot find symbol - variable t */
    System.out.println("You are buying " +n+ " tickets of " +cat+ " for Rs." +amt);
}
}
```

Comment: now it says variable t is already defined in main(Java.lang.String[])

Comment: Can you show me where you have "t" in your codes ? .... make sure only use  "t" that do not have "int" again

Answer (score 2):

Your 't' variable is declared within the case blocks repeatedly, which creates different variables. In this case, it can be seen only inside those blocks. You might consider putting the variable declaration before your switch block.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `t` is being declared **inside** the switch statement in the code above which is resulting in the error.You need to initialize it outside and change the value inside the switch statement accordingly.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cat;
        int t=0;
        System.out.println("Choose your category : \n 1)Premium - Rs.150 \n 2)Gold - Rs.200 \n 3)Business Class - Rs.400");
        cat = sc.nextInt();
        switch(cat)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Premium");
                t = 150;   /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Gold");
                t = 200;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Business Class");
                t = 400;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Option");
                break;
        }
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, amt;
        System.out.println("Choose number of tickets");
        n = num.nextInt();
        amt = t * n;      /* ERROR : cannot find symbol - variable t */
        System.out.println("You are buying " +n+ " tickets of " +cat+ " for Rs." +amt);
    }
```

}

Comment: now it says variable t is already defined in main(Java.lang.String[])

Answer (score -1):

Ok i figured it out, i had to put int t = 0; after the switch block not before.
When i put it before the switch block, it said variable t is already defined in main(Java.lang.String[]). The correct code is as following :

```
import java.util.*;
class Cinema
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int cat;
        System.out.println("Choose your category : \n 1)Premium - Rs.150 \n 2)Gold - Rs.200 \n 3)Business Class - Rs.400");
        cat = sc.nextInt();
        switch(cat)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Premium");
                int t = 150;   /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Gold");
                int t = 200;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                System.out.println("You have selected Business Class");
                int t = 400;  /* VARIABLE DECLARED */
                break;
            }
            default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Option");
            break;
        }
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n, amt;
        int t = 0;
        System.out.println("Choose number of tickets");
        n = num.nextInt();
        amt = t * n;      /* ERROR : cannot find symbol - variable t */
        System.out.println("You are buying " +n+ " tickets of " +cat+ " for Rs." +amt);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then the switch block accomplishes nothing and `t` is always 0 when you use it in `amt = t * n`.